# Making a game in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I'm making a typical defender arcade game on pygame for univeristy. My goal currently is to make the game pause and display a message whenever the player loses a life and resume with the next life when a key is pressed. This is the code for the hp and lives:

```
hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(shuttle,sprites, True)
if hit:
   shuttle.damage += 10 #increase damage
   tesla_sprite1 = aliens.Alien(screen, ai_settings, random.randrange(800, 
   ai_settings.screen_width),random.randrange(0, ai_settings.screen_height))
   sprites.add(tesla_sprite1)

if shuttle.damage == 100:
       shuttle.damage = 0
       you_crashed = "You have crashed!"
       you_crashed_label = crash_font.render(f"{you_crashed}",1, (255,0,0))
       screen.blit(you_crashed_label, (ai_settings.screen_width - 800, ai_settings.screen_height / 2))
```

Shuttle is an instance of a class, damage is hp and sprites is a sprite group containing enemies. ai_settings is a different module from which I borrow variables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To create a popup menu and stop a game you have to implement buttons and embed inner while loop inside main loop. You can draw buttons in that loop and also detect maouse input. When button gets pressed, simply change game state and break from the inner loop.